# Delete Production track from google play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I just published an app on the playstore, but I published it on **Production track** and I wanted it to be on **Closed tracks** for now, in **alpha version** so that it would only be downloaded by testers.

Is there an option that allows me to disable the Production track and later put it into production?

Thank you.

Comment: Any news/updates on this? I'm facing the same issue. Right now I have an app that is not in PROD yet, but it is already in production track. However we found that the app had issues and wanted to push a new version, but wanted for it to be in closed testing first. The thing is that now both apps get approved and if we publish, it will publish the together.